# How to show image as a Highslide popup in new view?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am displaying images in xtype:dataview as thumbnail. 
I am curious how to show the tapped image as a Highslide popup in a next view.
Can someone guide me in this? 
A sample code will be much help full.

Comment: please share what you have done till now

Comment: I have a list of categories and the Ext.dataview which display images in thumbnail. what i want is when i tap on an image it should navigate to next view and display image in highslide popup form.

Comment: attach a 'itemtap' listener to you dataview and write the code for popup. you will get all the info about the item clicked as parameter to it

Comment: or in the itemTpl define the onclick even and write the function in the index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a highslide gallery, with thumbnails underneath? There are lots of different types of highslides.

The best way would be to create a container with vbox....a carousel on top with a flex setting of 0.8, and a dataview underneath with a flex of 0.2.

Then, you can use the same store for both, load the dataview. Your tap listener for the dataview would do an animateactiveitem [index] of the carousel....the index will be take automatically from the dataview.

I ended up referring to the APOD carousel example by Ed SPencer, which pushes items into a carousel from a store first. The I loaded the store into both dataview and carousel at the same time, with an animateactiveitem showing the correct slide of the carousel on tap of the dataview.

I don't have my laptop here to post some example code, but maybe start by looking at the ed spencer APOD carousel.

Hope this helps....

:-)